# Finding the largest year interval in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have 10 years time and name associated to it like following,

```
Name Year
A    1990
B    1991
C    1992
A    1993
A    1994
.
.
.
```

I want to find the name that has been out of use for the longest time.

Can anybody help me how to do this?

Comment: By that do you mean you want to discover the "gap" for name "A" between 1990 and 1993?

Comment: @Larsenal yeah.. Suppose I have 100000 names, I want to find the name which has the maximum gap of years.

Comment: Do you mean you want the result to be `B` since it has been 24 years since then?

Comment: Really? I didn't get any "gap" in your question. A gap implies the longest time between two uses, whereas "out of use for the longest time" sounds to me like "the most recent use of the name is longest ago".

Comment: @Gregor Suppose the data set goes on till 2013 and each year has 200 names, and each name is repeated in some year, I want to find the name which was not used for maximum number of years.

Comment: @RichardScriven Suppose the data set goes on till 2013 and each year has 200 names, and each name is repeated in some year, I want to find the name which was not used for maximum number of years

Comment: For eg, if A,B, C doesn't occur hereafter in the dataset, my answer should be B because, it is the maximum years it has not been used

Comment: Okay, that's what my answer does.

Comment: @Gregor I get an error in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(your_data, max_year = max(Year)) %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarize(most_recent = max(Year),
              unused_length = first(max_year) - most_recent) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(most_recent)
```

This will order the names by their most recent use, with the oldest most recent use first.

If you only care about getting that one most out-of-use name, you just need the first row of the result. Add `slice(1)` to the chain as so:

```
mutate(your_data, max_year = max(Year)) %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarize(most_recent = max(Year),
              unused_length = first(max_year) - most_recent) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(most_recent) %>%
    slice(1)
```

Comment: I get an error "Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Added the `library(dplyr)`. Try again.

Comment: try `install.packages("magrittr")`

Comment: @Gregor Can we get the number of years it has not been used also?

Comment: @Gregor I am getting the follow error,

"Error: expecting a single value"

Comment: Fixed, needed a `first()`.

Comment: @Gregor i have one doubt.. suppose one name 'Gregor' was used first on 1880 and next time it was used on 2000. But many names have been used at 2013. I want 'Gregor' as output. does that happen here?

Comment: That does not happen here, but I can edit again. Do you want the opposite case handled as well? If your data goes back to 1880, and the name 'Gregor' shows up for the first time in 2013, do you want that to be count as 2013 - 1880 = 133 years of disuse, or do you only want to count time following the first recorded use?

Comment: @Gregor I want to find out which name has not been used for maximum number of period. Not only for the first recorded use, but maximum time for which it has not been used